# How to sort list of lists by name in r?

Tags: r, sorting

Let's say the data is;

```
data<-structure(list(`4` = 9, `3` = 7, `1` = 5, `2` = 4, `5` = 2), .Names = c("4", 
"3", "1", "2", "5"))
```

It looks like;

```
$`4`
[1] 9

$`3`
[1] 7

$`1`
[1] 5

$`2`
[1] 4

$`5`
[1] 2
```

But I want to sort list by lowest to highest like this;

```
out<-structure(list(`1` = 5, `2` = 4, `3` = 7, `4` = 9, `5` = 2), .Names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"))
```

Comment: Try `data[order(names(data))]`

Comment: @Sotos Very curious that the linked duplicate question's answer (from akrun) uses the exact same data in this question, but years before this was asked here.

Comment: @Gaffi What??? I did not see that! Actually the question has different data but akrun answer uses this same data here...I wonder if the data given here exists as part of some package..Nope nevermind. He creates it manually. Weird!!!

Comment: @Sotos Either that or some blog post/tutorial/similar. Inconsequential, but I found it interesting nonetheless.

Comment: @Sotos maybe `data[order(as.numeric(names(data)))]` is more general to deal with the names greater than 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a one-liner:

```
setNames(lapply(sort(names(data)), FUN = function(n) data[[n]]), sort(names(data)))

# $`1`
# [1] 5
# 
# $`2`
# [1] 4
# 
# $`3`
# [1] 7
# 
# $`4`
# [1] 9
# 
# $`5`
# [1] 2
```

Comment: Hey, this is a great solution but it'll mistake when adding "10"=5 in the data.

Answer (score 2):

You can sort by the names, then call the list by that sorted list:

```
data <- structure(list(`4` = 9, `3` = 7, `322` = 6, `1` = 5, `2` = 4, `5` = 2, `10` = 7),
              .Names = c("4", "3", "322", "1", "2", "5", "10"))
data <- data[order(as.numeric(names(data)))]

data
#$`1`
#[1] 5
#
#$`2`
#[1] 4
#
#$`3`
#[1] 7
#
#$`4`
#[1] 9
#
#$`5`
#[1] 2
#
#$`10`
#[1] 7
#
#$`322`
#[1] 6
```

Comment: Hey, this is a great solution but it'll mistake when adding `"10"=5` in your data.

Comment: You need `order`, not `sort`

Comment: @DarrenTsai Fixed with `as.numeric` as in Ben T.'s answer, thanks!

Comment: The output will be like you had never sorted them. You need to use `as.character` as in Ben T.'s answer and both your answers will be the same. Maybe you have to provide another answer or promote it.

Comment: @DarrenTsai I've added other numbers to the example, and using order (as Sotos noted), I do get accurate results. This is different from Ben's (order vs. sort) now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a two-liner: Create the sorting you want to have as a vector and reassign the sorted data

```
sorting <- sort(as.numeric(names(data)))
data <- data[as.character(sorting)]
```